# Why where's no changes for second column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change 2 columns in dataframe.

And It's working, but I can't make def with this code, it's not working.

```
import pandas as pd

def new_func(folder, file, types, folder1_changes: tuple):
    df = pd.read_csv(folder + '/' + file, encoding='1251').astype(types)
    for (i, j) in folder1_changes:
        try:
            product_names_list = list(df[i].unique())
            products_arr = np.array(range(1, len(product_names_list)+1))
            product_names_map = {}
            for a, p in zip(products_arr, product_names_list):
                product_names_map[p] = f'{j}{a}'

            df[i] = df[i].map(product_names_map)

        except KeyError:
            continue

        return df
```

My result is:

```
new_func(folder1_1, files1_1[1], folder1_types, folder1_changes)[['DR_NDrugs', 'DR_TDoc']].head(5)
```

|  | DR_NDrugs | DR_TDoc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Product_1 | Розничная реализация |
| 1 | Product_2 | Розничная реализация |
| 2 | Product_3 | Розничная реализация |
| 3 | Product_4 | Розничная реализация |
| 4 | Product_5 | Розничная реализация |

Why there's no change for 'DR_TDoc'?
Code working fine without def (I literally can copy/paste code outside function and it will work).

Comment: Probably because your return statement is indented too deeply.

Answer (score 0):

There's problem with return statement indent.
Function just returns result of first iteration of loop. (thx, to B Remmelzwaal).

```py
def new_func(folder, file, types, folder1_changes: tuple):
    df = pd.read_csv(folder + '/' + file, encoding='1251').astype(types)
    for (i, j) in folder1_changes:
        try:
            product_names_list = list(df[i].unique())
            products_arr = np.array(range(1, len(product_names_list)+1))
            product_names_map = {}
            for a, p in zip(products_arr, product_names_list):
                product_names_map[p] = f'{j}{a}'

            df[i] = df[i].map(product_names_map)

        except KeyError:
            continue

    return df
```